# Updating plot in real time

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am giving data to a matrix (e.g. with shape 100x100) by the following code:

```
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rand
tab = np.eye(100, 100)
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        tab[i, j] = rand.randint(0, 254)
        line1, = ax.plot(x, tab[i, :], 'r-')
        line1.set_ydata(tab[i, j])
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
    ax.lines.remove(line1)
```

I need to update matrix using loops and upgrade plot in the same time.
When loop with `j` ends, `i`-loop want to clear plot and start plotting again. Is it possible?

My result:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: i dont nderstand what youre trying to do here. why a 100x100 matrix? and why set_ydata after you set it once in the previous line? If youre trying to achieve something like the example picture you posted which if i'm right is a line plot of a bunch of random values then you dont need a 100x100 matrix you just need an array. If that is what youre inteding to do i can post the code as an answer

Comment: this is a short code showing what I have and what we need. I'm working on the biggest project that doesn't make sense to show. I create a 2.5D map based on the height from the sensor and I would like to show the entire cross-section in a given axis for a given row in real time. if the robot finished reading a given row, it wants the graph to clear and start drawing anew. that is, 100 charts

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment i think i understood what you where trying to do

the reason you got those horizontal lines was that you're setting ydata again after plotting(to a constant so its like plotting a horizontal line)

consider the code below:

```py
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rand
tab = np.eye(100, 100)
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        tab[i, j] = ((50-i/2)*(50-i/2)-(50-j)*(50-j))/100

for i in range(100):
    line1, = ax.plot(x, tab[i, :], 'r-')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    ax.lines.remove(line1)
```

I used another for to instantiate the tab map (since you're using sensor data I guess that is exactly what you're doing in your code because you need to read all of the data (at least the ones for the current cross section) to be able to plot the type of graph you want. this is equivalent to reading all of the data at the beginning and then starting to plot it)

(I also used simulated values instead of random values for the sake of testing)

if you want to draw the data AS THEY COME FROM THE SENSOR then you must define a function to get the data of the current cross section from the sensor and return an array. Idk the library you're using for the sensor but I'm assuming the scan functions are synchronous so the function will return exactly after the input is over making the whole thing pseudo-real time

```py
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rand
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


for i in range(100):
    data = READ_CURRENT_CROSS_SECTION()
    line1, = ax.plot(x, data, 'r-')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    ax.lines.remove(line1)
```

again, if plotting the data as the come from the sensor is your goal here it is going to depend a lot on the library you're using but except for all of that the problem with your code was that it was trying to plot while it was getting the data point by point which gives you insufficient data for plotting a cross section(hence the straight lines) (PS: there actually are some ways to pull it off like this but will be extremely slow!)

So either

1. write a function to scan the whole 2d area and return the whole map before you start plotting(which will be like my first code and the function i just said will replace lines 11-13). this takes away the real time feature but it will give you a beautiful animated plot in a short time
2. write a function to scan each cross section and return it as a 100 element array. which makes it kind of real time but i guess is harder to implement. This is like my second code but you have to define `READ_CURRENT_CROSS_SECTION` yourself